# What is REST and RESTFUL ROUTING and REST API in the case of ruby on rails?

Tags: rest, api, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

What is the difference between `REST` and `RESTFUL ROUTING` and `REST API`? in the case of `ruby on rails`. what is the practical implementation that we can see in the form of coding in `rails`? is there any difference between `REST` and `RESTFUL ROUTING` and `REST API` what is the relation between them?

Comment: I am also looking for answer of above question :(